# Pytorch Memory Issue When Running on EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, pytorch

I have a working Pytorch model on my desktop running CUDA 11.8 with my Nvidia 3070 GPU. Pytorch attempts to use way more memory on the instance (30GB) than on my desktop (6GB).

On my desktop, Pytorch uses approximately 6GB of memory on my GPU to run. However, when I run my model on an EC2 instance (g4dn.xlarge), Pytorch tries to use almost 30GB of memory, and my model won't run because my instance GPU (Nvidia T4) only has 16GB of memory. What I set up on the instance is identical to what I have been running on my desktop, and I have not been able to figure out why Pytorch uses so much more memory on the EC2 instance. Any help would be greatly appreciated.